# Definite Gaussian integral , need closed-form

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

I am trying to find a solution/approximation in closed-form for following integral

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{[\phi(x)]^2}{\Phi(x)}   \phi(a-bx) dx
\end{equation}

where $a,b$ are real and positive. And $\phi(x)$ is the standard normal(Gaussian) pdf and $\Phi(x)$ is standard normal(Gaussian) CDF. I.e $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ and $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} \phi(\alpha)d\alpha$.
I have tried by part integral with different approaches but in no avail. 
I am wondering can Mathematica solve this? (I don't have mathematica)

Comment: Since the error function is in the denominator, it doesn't seem promising, I highly suspect there's no closed form

Comment: There is most likely no closed form solution. This [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions) gives an overview over many transformation that might be well approximated, and the paper by Owen cited at the bottom is very helpful for finding such solutions systematically.